# Importing landing page traffic data from Google Analytics to Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-analytics, google-sheets-formula, google-analytics-api, google-sheets-api

I have a big list of landing pages on a spreadsheet. My goal is to get these landing pages' traffic data from Google Analytics within the last 9 months to my spreadsheet.

Is it possible to implement this with formulas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Google Analytics API, luckily there is an add-on that does the job for you:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on

The **Google Analytics Spreadsheet add-on** makes it easier for Google Analytics users to access, visualize, share, and manipulate their data in Google Spreadsheets.

Here you can find similar tool, **GA360 Unsampled Spreadsheet Add-on**, if you need to export Unsampled report in Spreadsheet from Google Analytics 360:

https://www.analyticstraps.com/google-analytics-unsampled-reports-spreadsheet-add-on/